# Get different JSON representations of the same object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given a java object which is serialised into a JSON string with Jackson.
Is it possible to control the serialisation process to generate different JSON outputs from the same object?

compressed:

```
{
  "a":"123",
  "s":"100"
}
```

or normal:

```
{
  "altitude":"123",
  "speed":"100"
}
```

EDIT:
The goal I want to achieve with this to have a long JSON format which is good for debugging (human-readable) and have a compressed format which is providing the smallest footprint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. It depends from your requirements. I suggest to implement your own property naming strategy. See below example:

```
class CompressedPropertyNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String translate(String name) {
        return String.valueOf(name.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CompressedPropertyNamingStrategy());
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Pojo());
```

If you do not want to compress property names, just remove line number 2.

**EDIT 1**
After @aumand comment I want to inform, that this solution will not work for entities which contain many properties which starts from the same letter. We have to write much sophisticated solution. For example:

```
class CompressedPropertyNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final int length;

    public CompressedPropertyNamingStrategy(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public String translate(String name) {
        if (name.length() < length) {
            return name;
        }

        return name.substring(0, length);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**
If you really want to have control on property names during serialization process, you should implement your own annotation. For example:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CompressedName {
    String value();
}
```

Your naming strategy in this case could look like this:

```
class CompressedPropertyNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method,
            String defaultName) {
        CompressedName compressedProperty = method.getAnnotation(CompressedName.class);
        if (compressedProperty != null) {
            return compressedProperty.value();
        }

        // Implement default value: first letter, or something else
        return defaultName;
    }
}
```

Now, you have to add annotation to your entity methods:

```
class Entity {

    private long altitude = 123;
    private int speed = 100;

    @CompressedName("a")
    public long getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }

    public void setAltitude(long altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }

    @CompressedName("sp")
    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

In this scenario example JSON could look like this:

```
{"a":123,"sp":100}
```

Comment: but beware that two properties starting with the same letter may cause problems using this approach.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I gave only idea and default implementation. Everyone can implement it in much sophisticated way.

Comment: The solution with the annotation looks good, just I still don't see how I can control if I want to generate the standard JSON or the compressed. As I can see if I add the `@CompressedName` then I won't be able to choose the long (standard) format programmatically.

Comment: By default, `ObjectMapper` uses default full-property-name convention. If you do not want to use custom naming-strategy, do not invoke `setPropertyNamingStrategy` method on `ObjectMapper` object.

Comment: Using the `CompressedPropertyNamingStrategy` (or `CompressedFieldNamingStrategy` with Gson) is working like charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library from Google. It is quite fast and flexible and offers the possibility to exclude (see [`@Foo`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization)) or rename fields (see [`@SerializedName("...")`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)) in the representation.

Just a proposal ... :)

**p.s.**: if you want to use more than one representation use the `FieldNamingStrategy` as Michael proposed, e.g.:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

if (format == "compressed") 
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingStrategy(new CompressedFieldNamingStrategy());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

...

class CompressedFieldNamingStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy
{
  private static HashTable translations = new HashMap<String, String>() {
      { put("altitude", "a"); put("speed", "s"); ...}
  };

  @Override
  public String translateName(Field field)
  {
    String name = field.getName();

    return translation.get(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the Gson library. However I don't know how I can programmatically choose to generate a compressed or a standard JSON format from the same object.

Comment: In Gson you have `FieldNamingStrategy`. You can use it like `PropertyNamingStrategy` in Jackson. See this URL: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html