# Using @JsonSomething to alias names

Tags: java, jackson

We have:

- a bunch of JSON variables with `names_all_lowercase_with_underscores`
- Java objects that **must** have the `usualCamelCaseNames`, due to a very tight Sonar checker (on which we can't change the rules).

To make things simpler:

- I'm trying to put some sanity in code that uses both V1 (codehaus) and V2 (fasterxml) versions (trying to keep only V2).
- Since several WS calls have the same outer control structure but different "payloads", the outer structure is a generic class:

  ```
  class Data<Payload> {
      private control_attr;
      private Payload pay_load;
  }
  ```

Ideally, there would be a "@JsonAlias("json_name") to put on every attribute and that would be used for serialization/deserialization.

```
  class Data<Payload> {
        @JsonAlias("control_attr")
        private String controlAttr;
        @JsonAlias("pay_load")
        private Payload payLoad;
    }
```

But this isn't how `@JsonAlias` works, unfortunately. I tried to put `@JsonProperty` on the attributes (without result) and even

```
 @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

But whatever I try the only thing that seems to count is the actual getter:

```
    @JsonGetter("control_attr")
    public String getControlXXXAttr { return controlAttr; }
```

sets a `controlXXXAttr` in the JSON(*). And unfortunately this is the solution I cannot use due to the Sonar checks mentioned above.

Am I missing something?

(*) since this is also a problem on the non-generic attribute, I assume that the generic class doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could consider a [`PropertyNamingStrategy`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html):

```java
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Consider, for example, the following class:

```java
@Data
public class Example {

    private String fooBar = "hey";
    private String fizBiz = "hey";
}
```

When serializing it to JSON:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Example());
```

You'll have the following:

```java
{"foo_bar":"hey","fiz_biz":"hey"}
```

The deserilization will also work:

```java
Example example = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);
```

Comment: That almost worked, unfortunately they have names like `foo_bar_1` that must become `fooBar1` for Sonar but that are Json-ified back to `foo_bar1` instead. But writing my own strategy is doable. Know of any example of such a custom one?

Comment: @xenoid, take a look on [Get different JSON representations of the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206706/get-different-json-representations-of-the-same-object), [Jersey Jackson JSON attribute change globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749919/jersey-jackson-json-attribute-change-globally), [Jackson - Modify an attribute at runtime without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915630/jackson-modify-an-attribute-at-runtime-without-annotation).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Data<Payload> {

@JsonProperty("control_attr", required = true)
private String controlAttr;
@JsonProperty("pay_load", required = true)
private Payload payLoad;

yours setter/getter       
 }
```

Comment: Had to use `@JsonProperty(value="control_attr", required = true)`, but no change.

Comment: In the second answer good example with object mapper.  We don't know which realization of server do you have.
For example, for `<jaxrs:server address="your/address"><jaxrs:providers> ref bean="jackson"/></jaxrs:providers>....</jaxrs:server> where 
<bean id="jackson" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"
          p:mapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
        <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>
    </bean>`